# How to inject @Value properties into beans defined using Spring 5 and Kotlin Bean Definition DSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dsl

I am developing a Spring Boot (2.0.0 M7) application using Kotlin, and need to define some beans taking advantage of the new DSL for bean definitions. I cannot come up with a way to inject values coming from @Value properties. Let's consider this simplified example:

```
fun beans() = beans {
    for (i in 1..10) {
        bean<String>("myString${i}" + someProperty) { "myString${i}" + someProperty}
    }
}
```

`someProperty` should come from something like this:

```
@Value("\${myProperty}") someProperty: String
```

How can I make it accessible to the `beans {}` DSL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved accessing the values through the env variable:

```
fun beans() = beans {
    for (i in 1..10) {
        bean<String>("myString${i}" + env.getProperty("myProperty") { "myString${i}" + env.getProperty("myProperty")}
    }
}
```

Comment: `env` is not accessible inside bean constructor. only within `BeanDefinitionContext`